# device admins onDisabled() not called in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, device-admin

I am developing one app which I am making my app device admin.I want to show custom message or dialog when user going to disable check box of app's device admin.How can I get or show activity(Custom Dialog) on Top of activity stack where dialog for Deactivate dialog shown by android OS?I am getting all the action of disable request and disabled after clicking on Deactivate but I want to show Custom Dialog before Deactivate dialog shown by android OS comes. How can I implement this kind of logic.Let me know the solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

`OnDisable` Will call only after disable occured If you want to display something when user pressed Disable use `Onrecieve` for ex:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 // detect whether disabling is requested?
 if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED)) {

     Toast.makeText(context, "Device Admin disabling now",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 } else {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
 }      
}
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent){
    super.onEnabled(context, intent);
    Log.d(TAG, "onEnabled");
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent){
    super.onDisabled(context, intent);
    Log.d(TAG, "onDisabled");
}
```

Comment: hey i want to start service when device admin is enable by clicking  activate button. will you please explain more...

Comment: @sunil you can override onEnabled method , when user accept device admin this method will call , you can start your service.

Comment: i know this methods as you said but  the method startService(Intent) is undefined it saying

Comment: @sunil you can start service using context ,  context.startService(new Intent(context, yourclass.java));

Comment: one more Question:can i listen cancel button just beside the activate button??

Comment: @sunil yes but not in this class , the class where you are firing admin rigths in onActivityResult you can get.

Comment: i am doing this Intent intent=
            new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, cn);
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
                        "test");
        startActivity(intent);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61751/discussion-between-sunil-and-pavanmvn).